# Number in brackets from PostgreSQL command in top

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Running the top-command `top -c` on an Ubuntu server shows all the commands that are currently running. Concerning PostgreSQL commands, what do the values in the brackets mean? I am speaking of the values right next to the red box in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not find any documentation to support this, but I believe it is the client's remote port.

The PostgreSQL server is listening on a specific port (5432 by default) and when a client contacts it via TCP the client provides an arbitrary port for the server to talk back to the client.  The red box in your example is covering the IP address of the client, that along with the port plus the IP:Port of the server makes up the unique connection.

Comment: It's the client's (remote) port, not the local port. The client connects *to* 5432, but connects from an arbitrary port. Just clarifying your phrasing here which could imply the client connects to or gets handed off to a random port number. That number can be used for identification, like `netstat -an | grep 41783` to find out which client it is.